# How do I find where a curve hits the $xy$ plane with vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces

I need to find $r'(t)$ and $||r'(t)||$ of $r(t)=<t,t,t^2>$, and tell where the curve hits the $xy$ plane (if it does). Also, I need to say something about how the curve looks like (do I just plot some points and figure out how it looks like?). I understand how to find $r'(t)$ and $||r'(t)||$, but how do I tell where the curve hits the $xy$ plane, and how do I describe the curve?

Here are my solutions for $r'(t)$ and $||r'(t)||$:

$r(t)=<t,t,t^2>$

$r'(t) = <1,1,2t>$

$||r'(t)||=\sqrt{2+4t^2}$

Comment: The $xy$-plane is the set of points where $z=0$.  For which $t$, if any, does $r(t)$ have a zero $z$-coordinate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers are correct, "hitting the xy-plane" means to find
$$\{r(t) | t\in\mathbb R, r(t)_3 = 0\} = \{r(t) | t\in\mathbb R, t^2 = 0\} = \{r(0)\} = \{\langle 0,0,0 \rangle\}$$
"Describing the curve" is, for example that the projection on the xz- and yz-plane of $r$ (i.e. $\pi_{xz} r(t) = \langle r(t)_1, 0, r(t)_3 \rangle$ and $\pi_{yz}$ analogously) is the graph of a parabola ($f(t) = t^2$).
It's a parabola in a certain plane (with normal vector $\langle 1, -1, 0\rangle$)... etc.